# Angular 2: access an element from the Component, getDocumentById doesn't work

Tags: angular, dom, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have an Angular 2 component where I want to retrieve an element div 
`<div id ="myId">` by its id.  I try doing: `document.getElementById("myId")` in my component (TypeScript), but i get an error: "cannot find name document".  I see that in other posts we can do something similar using @ViewChild, however I don't see how we can use this with a div, any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use @ViewChild with a div by adding a [TemplateRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html).

**Template**

```
    <div id ="myId" #myId>
```

**Component**

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myId') myId: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.myId.nativeElement);
    }
  }
```

[This blog post](http://angularjs.blogspot.jp/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) by Kara Erickson is a really good read for getting familiar with the Angular approach to doing things like this.

Comment: What if `id` is generated dynamically in `*ngFor` per item?

Comment: using the index property you can add an indexed template reference variable to elements created with *ngFor

Comment: but then you would have to dynamically generate the @ViewChild(...) annotations too, which is not possible. What if you do not know the length of the *ngFor list?

Answer (score 15):

Add *Template Reference variable* to the element you need access to:

```
<div #myDiv></div>
```

And in the component:

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

   constructor() {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.myDiv);
   }
}
```

Comment: What if `id` is generated dynamically?

Comment: @MarcinKapusta using ids is not recommended since in a platform like angular it's hard to avoid name collisions (if you have a lot of components). In what case will id be generated dynamically? The all point of identifiers is to be unique and expected.